# Why does this method of using trigonometric functions to calculate relativistic gamma work?

Tags: trigonometry, physics, special-relativity

When I studied special relativity, I noticed that some of the problems and answers on calculating $\gamma$ would be fractions of *c* that looked like ratios of side lengths in right triangles. For example, when $v = 4/5c$, $\gamma = 5/3.$ 
By playing around with trigonometric functions, I found an alternative formula to calculate $\gamma$,

$$ \gamma = \frac 1 {\sin(\arccos(\frac{v}{c}))} $$

I am not very familiar with trigonometric identities. Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\sin(\arccos(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ since $(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1)$

Comment: I'm not sure to what depth you want this question answered. I think the answers so far are reflecting how you are presenting the relationship. You might want to think more broadly about how $\gamma$ arises as this might help you with determining a more geometric/algebraic reason.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sin(\arccos x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
Draw the triangle: the hypotenuse is $1;$ the adjacent side is $x.$

By the Pythagorean theorem, the opposite side is $\sqrt{1-x^2}.$

Answer (score 2):

If you let $\theta=\arccos(\frac{v}{c})$, you have

$$\cos\theta= \frac vc,\>\>\>\>\>\sin\theta = \sqrt{1-\frac {v^2}{c^2}}$$

Then,

$$\sin \left(\arccos\frac{v}{c}\right) = \sin\theta 
= \sqrt{1-\frac {v^2}{c^2}} =\frac1{\gamma}$$